# Angular 6 - passing data between components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

I am learning angular 6 and typescript and have some problems with passing data between multiple components. It looks like on "expense-box.component.ts" component "this.participants" in ngOnInit method is null/empty. So I am not getting any data.

First (parent) component - **expense.component.ts**:

```
public participants = new Array<Participant>();

getParticipants(): void {
    this.participantService
      .getParticipants(token)
      .subscribe(participants => (this.participants = participants));
}
```

Participant service - **participant.service.ts** (to show whats inside getParticipants method)

```
  getParticipants(token: string): Observable<Participant[]> {
    return this.http.get<Participant[]>(`${this.url}/${token}`).pipe(
      tap(() => this.log(`Participants assigned to trip with token: ${token} fetched`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Participant[]>('getParticipants'))
    );
  }
```

It's html template - **expense.component.html**:

```
<app-expense-box *ngIf="selectedSplitTab == 1" [participants]="participants"></app-expense-box>
```

**expense-box.component.ts**

```
export class ExpenseBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() participants: Participant[];
  public equallyList = new Array<Equally>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.participants.forEach(element => {
      this.equallyList.push(new Equally(element.id, false, element.name));
    });
  }

  addExpense(): void {
    this.expense.equallyTab = this.equallyList;
    this.expenseService.addExpense(this.expense).subscribe(() => console.log('Expense added!'));
  }
}
```

It's html template - **expense-box.component.html**

```
<app-split-differently [equallyList]="equallyList" [splitEqually]="splitEqually"></app-split-differently>
```

It's child component - **split-differently.component.ts**

```
export class SplitDifferentlyComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() splitEqually: boolean;
  @Input() equallyList: Equally[];

  public selectedSplitTab = 1;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  enableSplitTab(selectedTab: number): void {
    this.selectedSplitTab = selectedTab;
  }
}
```

It's html template - **split-differently.component.html**

```
<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let item of equallyList">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="equallyTabParticipant{{item.userId}}" checked="{{item.checked}}">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="equallyTabParticipant{{item.userId}}">
    {{ item.userName }}
  </label>
  <hr>
</div>
```

In the end I want to have current state of EquallyList while sending it to the backend. Now nothing is even displayed, because I am doing something wrong (console not logging any errors).

Thanks to the answers in comments everything is displayed correctly now. I've checked one checkbox (other are unselected), clicked save button and all "checked" are set to false so values not binded properly. Here is screen with json which is sent to back-end:

[image]

Comment: have you set the value of selectedSplitTab  in expense.component.ts?

Comment: If you do `.subscribe(participants => (console.log(participants), this.participants = participants)` instead, what is printed?

Comment: Maybe participants is not initialized when loading the app-expense-box. Try changing your expense.component.html to: `<app-expense-box *ngIf="selectedSplitTab == 1 && participants.length" [participants]="participants"></app-expense-box>`

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes indeed I have this on expense.component.ts --> public selectedSplitTab = 1;

Comment: @user184994 I have changed code as you wish, and getting in console two objects (as it should be). So it looks like in this place everything works okey

Comment: @sanfalero it helped!. Could anyone explain me why it fixes the problem with displaying the data and passing trough components?

Comment: Because it won't initialise the `app-expense-box` until `participants` has at least one item in it

Comment: @user184994 Ok, it makes sense! Thanks for explanation. I've checked one  checkbox click save button, but all "checked" are false. Something still is wrong. Here is json which is sent to back-end {"equallyTab":[{"userId":23,"checked":false,"userName":"Tom"},{"userId":92,"checked":false,"userName":"Mathew"}],"token":"ddf90b46-127b-803b-9c14-b1c2a41b9373","userId":23}

Comment: There's no binding in that HTML, you'll need to add `[(ngModel)]="item.checked"` (and you can then remove `checked="{{item.checked}}"`)

Comment: @user184994 it worked! thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Your input might not received the data when you are trying to access it in ngOnInit() method.

You should use the setter method for your input and then do your stuff in that method.
Alternatively you can use ngOnChanges() hook

for ex:
with setter

```
@Input() myInput: any;

 set myInput() {
    //Do stuff here
}
```

with ngOnchanges

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChange){
if(changes['myInput']){
//Do stuff here
}
}
```